# Android Map: Save State of the map

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I have a Location button that takes to the map where user will select area and will press save button that displays toast and takes to the activity where it started, now i want to facilitate user to press Location button again it will show map with area that was selected, now if I use shared prefrences to save latitude and longitude using putfloat() in onPause(), and access these in onResume() I got to update camera and for this i need LatLng object, right? now problem is this I have latitude and longitude using shared prefrences and update camera require LatLng kind of thing, what I do

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();        
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("saved_area", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        float lat = pref.getFloat("lat", 0);
        float lng = pref.getFloat("lng", 0);
        float zoom = pref.getFloat("zoom", 0);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), zoom));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
       float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
       float lat = (float) map.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
       float lng = (float) map.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;

       SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("saved_area", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
       editor.putFloat("lat", lat);
       editor.putFloat("lng", lng);
       editor.putFloat("zoom", zoom);
       editor.commit();
       super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: The code in onResume is not running, when im including shared preferences it stops running and when i commented out that code it runs,